# Iterating over line index and printing the full line

Tags: python

I have this (kind of) big text file in which i have to find specific lines that tells the current action. For some of those lines I have find another line (usually 4-6 lines beneath) that tells information of said action.
My current script looks like this:

```
fileLines = file.readlines()
nrlines = enumerate(fileLines)
for i,line in nrlines:
    if "TiltArmAxis::StateGoingToAlmostUp" in line:
        print "%d - %s" % (i, line)
        for i,line in range(i, i+7):
            if "Axis::StatePositionMode:" in line:
                print "%d - %s" % (i, line)
```

It works in the first for but not in the second, I get:

```
4520 - "2014-11-13 08:13:43",T:305310  TiltArmAxis - changing state from TiltArmAxis::StateAtDown -> TiltArmAxis::StateGoingToAlmostUp
```

But then:

```
for i,line in range(i, i+7):
TypeError: unpack non-sequence
```

So basically, I want to fist index every line with enumerate, then find the lines with "TiltArmAxis::StateGoingToAlmostUp" in them and print. Then look in the next 6 lines for "Axis::StatePositionMode:" and if such line occur (if not, skip it); print it and go to next "TiltArmAxis::StateGoingToAlmostUp".

Is there a more effective way of doing this? Please help

EDIT: Removed args,

```
range(i, i+7):
```

Still get the same error

Comment: is that all your code? you may change `args` in between. what if you use `range(i, i+7)`?

Comment: Why do you use args instead of just using `range(i, i+7)`? The answer is probably the source of your problem.

Comment: This is just one part of the code, "StateGoingToAlmostUp" is one of 16 actions.

Comment: How big files to process? What to do when being on the line `N` and the "Axis::StatePositionMode:" string is not found in the next 6 lines? Shall we start looking for the ""TiltArmAxis::StateGoingToAlmostUp" string on the line `N+1`?

Comment: Well, the first line with "TiltArmAxis::StateGoingToAlmostUp" is line 4520, next in line 10908.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`range(i, i+7)` is a simple sequence of **integers** between `i` and `i+7`. What you need is :

```
nrlines = enumerate(file)
for i,line in nrlines:
    if "TiltArmAxis::StateGoingToAlmostUp" in line:
        print "%d - %s" % (i, line)
        for j in range(7):
            i, line = next(nrlines)  # use next on the iterator !
            if "Axis::StatePositionMode:" in line:
                print "%d - %s" % (i, line)
```

BTW, you should protect the `next` with a `try: ... except StopIteration: ...` to avoid error if you reach end of file during the inner loop. I cannot do it, because I do not really know what you want to do in except case :-)

Comment: Do you think it would be nice on a file of size 10 G bytes? Please do not load everything in memory when it is useless. Disk are still much bigger than RAM ... ;-) In other words: What's returned from `file.readlines()`?

Comment: @dlask : Ouch :-( . I did not notice the unnecessary `readlines` in original code because it used enumerate. I've just removed it, but you are right, I'd make the same mistake I said you made. I must apologize for it ...

Answer (score 1):

We can simply index the list of lines.

```
with open("test.txt", "rt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        if "TiltArmAxis::StateGoingToAlmostUp" in lines[i]:
            print "%d - %s" % (i, lines[i])
            for j in range(i, min(i+7, len(lines))):
                if "Axis::StatePositionMode:" in lines[j]:
                    print "%d - %s" % (j, lines[j])
```

Alternatively, we can still use `enumerate`:

```
with open("test.txt", "rt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if "TiltArmAxis::StateGoingToAlmostUp" in line:
            print "%d - %s" % (i, line)
            for j, line in enumerate(lines[i:i+7]):
                if "Axis::StatePositionMode:" in line:
                    print "%d - %s" % (i+j, line)
```

And finally a solution that doesn't load the whole file to RAM. It's based on assumption that the string "TiltArmAxis::StateGoingToAlmostUp" doesn't appear again in the next 6 lines.

```
with open("test.txt", "rt") as f:
    look_for_next = False
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if look_for_next:
            if i < limit:
                if "Axis::StatePositionMode:" in line:
                    print "%d - %s" % (i, line)
                    look_for_next = False
            else:
                look_for_next = False
        else:
            if "TiltArmAxis::StateGoingToAlmostUp" in line:
                print "%d - %s" % (i, line)
                look_for_next = True
                limit = i + 7
```

Comment: I really appreciate it. Unfortunately, I have to use python 2.4.4 (It's for work), so I can't really use these. Thanks anyways.